# create csv and write to it using Photoshop-script

Tags: javascript, excel, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to create an excel file with the contents using Photoshop script. Any hints on how to create a sheet and write to the cell?

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible? One can't normally create excel files using photoshop. What research have you done?

Comment: @Anantha I read your question serveral times and I am still not able to understand what exactly do you want to do. Some things confusing me.

Comment: i am new to scripting, i want to store the bounds into an excel/csv file. as of now i am creating excel file as:  var logFile = new File(logFileName); and writing the content to it as logFile.writeln(content); With this i am able to write the content as rows, but i want the data to be in columns. So i want to know if there is any way to create a sheet, and a cell, and then write data in to that cell

Answer (score 2):

Creating a CSV file which can be opened in any spreadsheet (including Excel) is fairly simple. While scripting in Photoshop (or any adobe software with scripting support) you can you Extended Script's File object.

**CSV file**

CSV (Comma-Separated Values) is a simple text file where each **cell** in a row is separated by comma (other separators also possible). Cell values might be also enclosed in quotation marks.

**Before you start**

So first and foremost you need to have your data ready. Since I don't know what you want to write I cannot help you with this. But let's assume you have your data in an array of arrays. Each array being a single row. In that case you could simply do the following.

**Writing file**

```
/**
    data is an array of arrays, example: 
    data = [
            ['first layer', 400, 500], 
            ['second layer', 300, 500],
            ['awesome layer', 500, 500],
           ] 
**/

var file = new File('D:\path\to\file.csv');
file.open('w');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    file.writeln('"' + data[i].join('","') + '"');
}
file.close();
```

Simple as that.

File contents would be:

```
"first layer","400","500"
"second layer","300","500"
"awesome layer","500","500"
```

I'm using comma separator and enclose data in quotations marks but quotation marks might not be needed if for example all data will be numbers. Also please remember that if float values are going to be written with comma as decimal separator (depending on local options) you can also use semicolon as separ

However depending on permissions and/or existence of files/folders on certain path - both `open` method and `writeln` method might return false. So you should update following code to detect those scenarios if necessary.

Comment: hello, i want to write the data(here my data is layer name along with layer width and height) into columns. First column would contain all the layer names, next column should contain corresponding width and height. Using the above code i will be able to write everything in single line :(

Comment: Why single line? `Writeln` method creates a whole line in file, next call creates another line. See my updated example.

Comment: You might want to reverse the direction of the loop as Photoshop works from the bottom layer up; but humans tend to work from the top layer down.